# submitting multiple forms on single click via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am `submitting multiple forms` on `single button` click.

**e.g.** suppose i have two forms. On button click, i can see `$('form[id^=buyerForm]').length gives 2.`

The `first iteration` picks `first form data` and make ajax call but `second iteration` also `picks the first form data`. `This is the problem.`

Can anyone please explain why iteration always picks first form data?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#jPdetails").on('click', function() {
        $('form[id^=buyerForm]').each(function() {
            post_form_data($(this).serialize());
        });
    });

        function post_form_data(data) {
            var jsellerAddress = $("#jsellerAddress").val();
            var jagentId = $("#jagentId").val();
            var jbuilding = $("#jbuilding").val();
            var junitId = $('#junitId option:selected').val();
            var jpropertyAed = $("#jppropertyAed").val();
            var jparkingBaysAt = $("#jparkingBaysAt").val();
            var jtotalAed = $("#jtotalAed").val();
            var dataString =
                'jsellerAddress=' + jsellerAddress +
                '&jagentId=' + jagentId +
                '&jbuilding=' + jbuilding +
                '&junitId=' + junitId +
                '&jpropertyAed=' + jpropertyAed +
                '&jparkingBaysAt=' + jparkingBaysAt +
                '&jtotalAed=' + jtotalAed;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'jointpurchasehandller.php',
                data: dataString,
                success: function(result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
        };
</script>
```

**html**
my html structure

```
<div id="jointBuyer" class="JointBuyerDive" style="display:none">
    <div id="jBuyer">
        <div id="inner"class="col-lg-6">
            <form id="buyerForm" role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

and i'm adding `multiple forms` the following way

```
<script
    function addBuyer() {
        $("#addBuyer").click(function() {
            $("#buyerForm").clone().appendTo("#jointBuyer");
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: please add the html part

Comment: **ID should always be unique** this why you only get the first data because other forms are duplicate ID only use class instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never ever use ids in loops NEVER:

```
 $("#jPdetails").on('click', function() {
        $('form[id^=buyerForm]').each(function(i,v) {
            post_form_data($(v).serialize(),v);
        });
    });

        function post_form_data(data,el) {
            var jsellerAddress = $(el).find("#jsellerAddress").val();
            var jagentId = $(el).find("#jagentId").val();
            var jbuilding = $(el).find("#jbuilding").val();
            var junitId = $(el).find('#junitId option:selected').val();
            var jpropertyAed = $(el).find("#jppropertyAed").val();
            var jparkingBaysAt = $(el).find("#jparkingBaysAt").val();
            var jtotalAed = $(el).find("#jtotalAed").val();
            var dataString =
                'jsellerAddress=' + jsellerAddress +
                '&jagentId=' + jagentId +
                '&jbuilding=' + jbuilding +
                '&junitId=' + junitId +
                '&jpropertyAed=' + jpropertyAed +
                '&jparkingBaysAt=' + jparkingBaysAt +
                '&jtotalAed=' + jtotalAed;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'jointpurchasehandller.php',
                data: dataString,
                success: function(result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
        };
```

or change all the ids to classes

```
 $("#jPdetails").on('click', function() {
        $('.buyerForm').each(function(i,v) {
            post_form_data($(v).serialize(),v);
        });
    });

        function post_form_data(data,el) {
            var jsellerAddress = $(el).find(".jsellerAddress").val();
            var jagentId = $(el).find(".jagentId").val();
            var jbuilding = $(el).find(".jbuilding").val();
            var junitId = $(el).find('.junitId option:selected').val();
            var jpropertyAed = $(el).find(".jppropertyAed").val();
            var jparkingBaysAt = $(el).find(".jparkingBaysAt").val();
            var jtotalAed = $(el).find(".jtotalAed").val();
            var dataString =
                'jsellerAddress=' + jsellerAddress +
                '&jagentId=' + jagentId +
                '&jbuilding=' + jbuilding +
                '&junitId=' + junitId +
                '&jpropertyAed=' + jpropertyAed +
                '&jparkingBaysAt=' + jparkingBaysAt +
                '&jtotalAed=' + jtotalAed;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'jointpurchasehandller.php',
                data: dataString,
                success: function(result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
        };
```

or:

```
$("#jPdetails").on('click', function() {
    $('form[id^=buyerForm]').each(function(i,v) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'jointpurchasehandller.php',
            data:$(v).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: don't know whether your answered or not? but your code does not work for me.

Comment: what do you mean by "does not work for me" what errors do you have,provide the html, did i say never use ids in loops?

Comment: oh very sorry. Your solution worked for me. I just re checked your code.But can you exaplain what is v in the this line to understand your answer better. post_form_data($(v).serialize(),v);

Comment: v is the form element

Comment: Thanks for help. nicely explained.

Comment: in this scenario, how to stop submitting form if it is is not touched by user. Its just added but nothing input.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: I clicked Add button 3 times, so i have 3 forms showing. But i entered data only in the first form. Other 2 forms are untouched. So when i am doing submit, i want to exclude two forms ajax call.

Comment: use some validation on the form man test if the values are imputed,correct,valid then submit

Comment: Yeah i was thinking the same but just wanted to rule that there is nothing i can do at form level just. thanks man again

Answer (score 0):

I think you can reduce the code size to

```
$("#jPdetails").on('click', function() {
    $forms=$('form[id^=buyerForm]');
    $($forms).each(function(index) {
        // this will bind corresponding data for each form
        dataString=$($forms[index]).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'jointpurchasehandller.php',
            data: dataString,
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: use field name same as 'jsellerAddress','jagentId'... as listed in your form